# Emptying all site recycle bins

Tags: 2007, recycle-bin

Is it possible to empty all recycle bins in a site collection? I tried going into the recycle bin located on the admin page but it was empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following powershell script will delete all items in the site collection recycle bin  and recycle bins of each of the webs in the provided sitecollection url:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint");
$site = new-object microsoft.sharepoint.spsite("SITE COLLECTION URL");
for ($i=0;$i -lt $site.allwebs.count;$i++)
{ 
  if($site.allwebs[$i].recyclebin.count >0)
{
  $site.allwebs[$i].recyclebin.deleteall();
}}
$site.recyclebin.deleteall();
$site.dispose();
```